# Sudden Warning on XCode 5.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I suddenly started getting this error after upgrading my **Xcode 5.0.2** to **Xcode 5.1**

```
warning: ignoring debug info with an invalid version (0)
```

There are like **22** of these **warnings** coming up when compiling my code...

I haven't encountered anything like this before… Please can anyone help.. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XCode target BuildSettings, search `DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING` and set Value to NO.

This is a bug with LTO and -dead_strip.  The workaround is to stop using one of them.

way Link Time Optimization (LTO) works is that the compiler stops half way through and emits the .o file as "bit code" (the internal clang IR) instead of compiling down to mach-o.  This is drive by the -flto compiler option. When the linker encounters bit-code .o files, it loads up the back end of clang (libLTO.dylib) and merges/compiles all the bit-code files into mach-o then completes the link.

[The Link](https://devforums.apple.com/message/950372#950372)

Comment: after doing this the warning went away.. i closed Xcode.. now when i have reopened it the warning is back...

Comment: Now em also getting this `WARNING: Linking two modules of different target triples: 'x86_64-apple-ios7.0.0' and 'x86_64-apple-ios6.0.0'`

Comment: Sorry that I haven't meet such a warning. Do you try set Value back to  YES, will the warning disappear?

Comment: @AhmedZ.Were you able to fix that warning?

Answer (score 1):

Check files that are related to warnings. If will be probably a third party library. Try to recompile that lib with new Xcode.

Comment: i have a lot of libraries in my project... how would i recompile them?

Comment: Does it show name of affected file at the end of warning? If so it will tell you which lib you should recompile. If you don't have source codes, try to find them or contact the developers.

Comment: Indeed third party libraries cause these warning , I am facing the same problem,seems there are no ways to fix this unless the library provider provide a new version library, I hope I am wrong about that.

Comment: please tell me how to recompile the lib with new xcode