# Sudden Warnings after upgrading to XCode 5.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-warnings

I just stumbled upon 2 warnings in my project that are really confusing..

**1.**
    `warning: ignoring debug info with an invalid version (0)`

**2.**
    `WARNING: Linking two modules of different target triples: 'x86_64-apple-ios7.0.0' and 'x86_64-apple-ios6.0.0'`

the first one was resolved by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22626889/1042240) answer's help. But after restarting my Xcode I got the warning again…

The second one just appeared and i can't find anything on google for this…

THanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Items:

- You should for sure clean your Xcode project (⇧⌘K). Personally, I like to clean the entire derived data directory (⌥⇧⌘K), AKA ["nuke the entire site from orbit..."](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCbfMkh940Q).
- I had some problems after upgrading too. FWIW, Xcode 5.1 defaults Simulator builds to "active architecture", which for most folks is `x86_64` now. Previously, I think the default architecture for sim builds was `i386`. This might be part of your problem with #2.
- Re: #2, one of those modules is compiled against the iOS6 SDK, and one is iOS7. Clean might help, or you might need to reset the `Base SDK` in Build Settings to `Latest iOS` on all your submodules.

Comment: Ok got the second one fixed… thanks… but still first one is there… :o

Comment: Do you know what fixed #2? For posterity.

Comment: I changed the deployment target and architecture and build architecture a couple of times of both target and project and i think that did the trick..